# Visual Basic get all profiles from registry sub folder

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find every sub folder of the profiles for a program called AutoCAD.

I have managed to specify a specific profile, but I would like to be able to find all the profiles.

This is what i have so far to get one particular profile (its the default profile on all computers)

```
Dim readValue2014 As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
        "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\<<Unnamed Profile>>\Dialogs\Appload\Startup", "NumStartup", Nothing)
```

Unnamed Profile is the default profile. As you can see there are other folders after it which I need to get the value NumStartup from.

So what I need is a way to get the list of sub folders from the folder Profiles.

I assume then I can just string the other sub folders on the end of the list i get of profiles.

I just have no idea how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Use RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the RegistryKey class instead of the My. helper classes.

```
RegistryKey softwareKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software")
RegistryKey autodeskKey = softwareKey.OpenSubKey("Autodesk")
```

and so on... and finally:

```
Dim profileNames() As String = profilesKey.GetSubKeyNames()
```

PS: You need to
    Import Microsoft.Win32

Comment: awesome, thanks for that, I will try it out. Just one more question, how do I import? I am new to visual basic, just started last night